# Cannot get QString data from another header file

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a login window where users input some text.

login.cpp:

```
#include "login.h"
#include "ui_login.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

login::login(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::login)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setFixedSize(320,212);
    connect(ui->_login, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(rLogin()));
    connect(ui->_close, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(rClose()));
}

login::~login()
{
    delete ui;
}

void login::rLogin()
{
    prefix = ui->_prefix->text();
    site = ui->_site->text();
    dbname = ui->_database->text();
    user = ui->_username->text();
    QString pass = ui->_password->text();
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName(site);
    db.setDatabaseName(prefix + dbname);
    db.setUserName(prefix + user);
    db.setPassword(pass);
    bool logged = db.open();
    if (logged) {
        rOpen();
    } else {
        int warning = QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Hostel ERP Error"),
                                           tr("Could not connect to database.\n"
                                              "Please check your inputs."),
                                           QMessageBox::Ok);
    }
}

void login::rOpen()
{
    mainwindow* openwindow = new mainwindow();
    openwindow->show();
    this->close();
}

void login::rClose()
{
    this->close();
}
```

prefix, site, dbname, and user are defined as QString in login.h
login.h:

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class login;
}

class login : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit login(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void rOpen();
    QString prefix;
    QString site;
    QString dbname;
    QString user;
    ~login();
```

I am trying to access prefix, site, dbname, and user from mainwindow.cpp

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QSql>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QAction>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <login.h>

namespace Ui {
class mainwindow;
}

class mainwindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit mainwindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void rPopulate();
    QPushButton *button;
    login * log;
    ~mainwindow();
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "login.h"
#include "newbooking.h"
#include <qaction.h>
//somecode
login *log = new login;
QString table_schema = log->prefix + log->dbname;
```

however both log->prefix and log->dbname are empty. There is default text in  ui->_prefix->text(); and ui->_database->text(); so they shouldn't be empty.

Comment: Do you mean to access the `log` that is a member of `mainwindow`? When you create a `new login`, they are ofcourse going to have default values, i.e empty.

Comment: The values are copied from ui->_prefix etc. in rLogin, I don't see that method called.

Comment: @KarthikT no, im trying to access the QStrings in login.h
FrankOsterfeld I included the whole login.cpp file now

Comment: @CppandQtBeginner perhaps you need to take some time to read up on object oriented programming? The strings are not in a file, they are in a specific object of `login`. You need to access them from that object

Comment: @CppandQtBeginner I agree with Karthik, that you should learn more about object oriented programming and C++. You are creating a new login object in the mainwindow class and a new mainwindow object in the login class. Usually you only use a single mainwindow, and it's  created in the main function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to declare QString as global var at the top of login.h in between #include "mainwindow.h" and  login::login(QWidget *parent):, then in login.cpp define the QStrings.

eg. login.h

```
#include ...
extern QString site; //this
login::login(QWidget *parent) :
```

login.cpp

```
#include ...
QString example; //this
login::login(QWidget *parent) :
```

after that you can simply call them from whatever file you want. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely trying to access `mainwindow::log` i.e the log that is a member of `mainwindow`. You probably call `rLogin` on this function.

However you are getting empty values because you are creating a new object which has default values.

```
login *log = new login;
```

This line is part of the problem I assume. We wont know more before you show us how you call `rLogin`, but you want to check from the same object that you call it on.

Comment: login.cpp/ui/h is the first files loaded, rLogin is called when the Login button is clicked. (I updated login.cpp to include the whole file)

Comment: You create a new login object and then access its prefix member immediately. At this point, nothing has happened, the dialog wasn't even visible. You must wait until rLogin() was triggered and then continue (e.g. by connecting to a signal loggedIn() you add to login and emit at the end of rLogin)